# How to deserialise an async function name and call it with deserialised arguments

Tags: rust, serde

I have an idea for a Rust project where I would like to have a reusable library that allows a TOML file to specify a sequence of functions to be called, along with the required arguments to pass to those functions. These functions need to be asynchronous.

I want something like:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    functions: IndexMap<String, dyn Fn() -> dyn Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>>,
}
```

But this doesn't work (for multiple reasons I think).

I have managed to get a PoC to work using an Enum as an intermediate type:

```
use indexmap::IndexMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use toml::toml;

async fn without_args() -> Result<(), ()> {
    println!("Function without args");
    Ok(())
}

async fn with_args(arg: &str) -> Result<(), ()> {
    println!("Function with the arg = {arg}!");
    Ok(())
}

async fn sum_args(x: u64, y: u64) -> Result<(), ()> {
    println!("Function for the sum {x} + {y} = {}!", x + y);
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "function", content = "args")]
enum FnOptions {
    Without,
    With(String),
    Sum(u64, u64),
}

impl FnOptions {
    async fn perform(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        match self {
            FnOptions::Without => without_args().await,
            FnOptions::With(arg) => with_args(arg).await,
            FnOptions::Sum(x, y) => sum_args(*x, *y).await,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    functions: IndexMap<String, FnOptions>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let toml = toml! {
        [functions.foo]
        function = "Without"

        [functions.bar]
        function = "With"
        args = "baz"

        [functions.sum]
        function = "Sum"
        args = [ 1, 2 ]
    };
    let config: Config = toml.try_into().unwrap();

    for func in config.functions {
        func.1.perform().await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

I can also remove the Enum and just use a match statement that matches the function name directly to the function to be called but I think this is cleaner.

However, this isn't generic enough for a library as the user would need to manually maintain the Enum and the `perform()` function that calls the correct function based on the Enum variant.

Maybe I could create a macro to do this but I don't have much experience with macros (none with proc-macros).

I'm hoping that I'm missing an obvious solution.

Comment: How you can serialize and deserialize a function? It seems like you want to create a programming language, and this definitely doesn't have an obvious solution.

Comment: At some point, you have to give the compiler a mapping of the string in the config file to the corresponding function. Whether that be a `match`, an `enum`, a `HashMap`, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a global map of names to functions and you could register functions that can be called from the config.

```rust
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

use futures::future::BoxFuture;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

pub type FnOut = BoxFuture<'static, Result<(), ()>>;

pub enum FnArgs {
    NoArgs,
    OneArg(String),
    TwoArgs(String, String),
    ThreeArgs(String, String, String),
    // ...
}
pub struct FnConfig {
    pub name: String,
    pub args: FnArgs,
}

type GenericFn = Box<dyn Fn(FnArgs) -> FnOut + Send>;

lazy_static! {
    static ref REGISTERED_FUNCTIONS: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, GenericFn>>> =
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
}

pub fn register(name: impl Into<String>, f: GenericFn) {
    REGISTERED_FUNCTIONS.lock().unwrap().insert(name.into(), f);
}

pub fn perform(f: FnConfig) -> FnOut {
    let functions = REGISTERED_FUNCTIONS.lock().unwrap();
    functions.get(&f.name).unwrap()(f.args)
}
```

and then you would use the library like this

```rust
use futures::FutureExt;
use my_lib::{perform, register, FnArgs, FnConfig, FnOut};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use toml::toml;

// Better implement Deserializer for FnArgs instead of using intermediate struct.
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct _FnConfig {
    name: String,
    args: Vec<String>,
}
impl From<_FnConfig> for FnConfig {
    fn from(value: _FnConfig) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: value.name,
            args: match value.args.as_slice() {
                [] => FnArgs::NoArgs,
                [arg1] => FnArgs::OneArg(arg1.to_owned()),
                [arg1, arg2] => FnArgs::TwoArgs(arg1.to_owned(), arg2.to_owned()),
                [arg1, arg2, arg3] => {
                    FnArgs::ThreeArgs(arg1.to_owned(), arg2.to_owned(), arg3.to_owned())
                }
                _ => unimplemented!(),
            },
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    functions: Vec<_FnConfig>,
}

fn without_args(args: FnArgs) -> FnOut {
    if let FnArgs::NoArgs = args {
        async move {
            println!("Function without args");
            Ok(())
        }
        .boxed()
    } else {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn with_args(args: FnArgs) -> FnOut {
    if let FnArgs::OneArg(arg) = args {
        async move {
            println!("Function with the arg = {arg}!");
            Ok(())
        }
        .boxed()
    } else {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn sum_args(args: FnArgs) -> FnOut {
    if let FnArgs::TwoArgs(arg1, arg2) = args {
        let (arg1, arg2): (u64, u64) = (arg1.parse().unwrap(), arg2.parse().unwrap());
        async move {
            println!("Function for the sum {arg1} + {arg2} = {}!", arg1 + arg2);
            Ok(())
        }
        .boxed()
    } else {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    register("Without", Box::new(without_args));
    register("With", Box::new(with_args));
    register("Sum", Box::new(sum_args));

    let toml = toml! {
        functions = [
            { name = "Without", args = [] },
            { name = "With", args = ["baz"] },
            { name = "Sum", args = ["1", "2"] },
        ]
    };
    let config: Config = toml.try_into().unwrap();
    for func in config.functions.into_iter().map(Into::into) {
        perform(func).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

This is just a quick implementation and it could definitely be improved. This is just to give you an idea. E.g. registered functions don't have to be global. You could have a struct that contains the functions and has methods `register` and `perform`. You could implement deserializer for `FnArgs` instead of using intermediate struct for conversion. You could use `Vec<String>` as args, but I used enum as example, so you could have some variants to avoid parsing (e.g. you could have special variant for integer args). This is mostly to give you ideas how you could implement this feature.

The downside is that all functions that can be accessed through config have to have the same signature and they need to parse their arguments. It might be possible to remove some boilerplate by using proc macros, but I don't have much experience with that.

Comment: (This is one of those cases where the [ctor](https://docs.rs/ctor/latest/ctor/) crate is worth mentioning.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was very clear and helpful! Plus, the example you gave worked perfectly :)
I didn't know about the `BoxFuture` type which helps a lot. I managed to get something working with the changes you mentioned and some additions so that serde works with a single enum with the args for each function. It is a shame that there is still some boilerplate about registering these functions and the fact that the user has to make a new enum variant for each function but maybe a proc-macro can remove some of this boilerplate with the use of the `ctor` crate recomended by @Caesar